# Reduce method in the stock picker exercise?

Tags: ruby, each, reduce, enumerable

The problem gives an array where each index is the price of a stock in each day:

```
array = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]
```

For example, 1st of November the price is $17, 2nd of November the price is $3, 3rd of November the price is $6, etc.

I have to find the best days to buy and sell, so it should return [#{buy_day}, #{sell_day}]

The correct answer in this case is [1, 4] for a profit of $12 (buy at $3 and sell at $15). To do this, I used the reduce method and it works fine, but I was told I am not using the reduce method correctly.

```
stock = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]
stocks_new = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]
best_profit = 0
days = []

stock.length.times do |day|
  stocks_new.reduce do |acc, val|
    acc = stocks_new[0]
    profit = val - acc
    if profit > best_profit
      best_profit = profit
      days = [stock.index(acc), stock.index(val)]
    end
  end
  stocks_new.shift
end
```

I first copied the array onto another variable (stocks_new), and I shift at the end of every loop. I do this to avoid the val in |acc, val| from starting behind the accumulator in the iteration.

Is there a way to set the val in reduce method to start from the acc + 1 index on each iteration so i don't have to create this stocks_new array and shift each time?

Comment: FYI: [Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) (the elements being the relative stock price changes from one day to the next)

Comment: Yes, you are not using `reduce` correctly. You are using it as an `each`. This is like using a big wrench as a hammer. Sure it works. But that's not its intended purpose and it can do more.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is reduce still viable to use for this problem? Or is it better to go with each with index as the answer below did?

Comment: @sorrowlol Your original implementation appears to be horribly inefficient (O(N^3), at a glance), and this is not because of `reduce`. It's better to use a linear complexity algorithm, like the one in Sash's answer. You can use reduce there too, by moving all that state (`max_profit`, `sell_day`, etc.) into the acc/memo.

Comment: @Sergio, I'm confused as well. I thought I read one must sell before buying, which I found very odd, but I have no idea how I had that impression. I can now see there's a one-pass solution for both interpretations. My answer now resides in the waste bin, awaiting garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about reduce method issue, but maybe you could consider a one-pass solution, that does not need any copying:

```
def max_profit(stock)
    min_price = (1 << 31) - 1  # stock.max
    max_profit = 0
    min_day_index = 0
    sell_day = 0
    buy_day = 0
    stock.each_with_index do |price, day_index|
        if price < min_price
            min_price = price
            min_day_index = day_index
        end
        profit = price - min_price
        if profit > max_profit
            max_profit = profit
            sell_day = day_index
            buy_day = min_day_index
        end
    end
    max_profit > 0 ? [buy_day, sell_day] : "Cannot make profit"
end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, you first need to **buy** the stock before selling. In this case, we get [7, 4] which is not possible since the days in the array are in consecutive order [1st of November, 2nd of Nevember, 3rd of November..-1]

Comment: @sorrowlol Good catch should work as expected now.

Comment: `(0...stock.size).to_a.combination(2).max_by{|a,b| stock[b] - stock[a] }` is another idea.